# excluding UIDevice from a static library

Tags: xcode, static-libraries, uniqueidentifier, uidevice

I create a static library which include a usage of the UIDevice. There is no use of the uniqueIdentifier.

Apple rejected an app suing this library and we suspect it's because searching for the uniqueIdentifier in the *.a return a match:

```
$ find .|grep "\.a"|grep -v "\.app"|xargs grep uniqueIdentifier
```

It's enough to have the following line in the code to get a match on the above command.

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
```

Is there a way to tell Xcode to exclude the UIDevice from the build files?

Comment: i have the same issue, was there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
In my code I was initializing UIDevice object using code :

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
```

then I was getting systemversion using  `[device systemVersion]` which was showing matches for uniqueIdentifier after executing `grep` command.

So instead of initializing the device object , I just retreived the systemVersion staightaway:

```
NSString *systemver= [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] ;
```

which solved my problem . Hope this solves yours as well.